# JDBC exception when trying to use a prepared statement placeholder as an argument to an aggregation function

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, druid, apache-calcite

I'm attempting to use a PreparedStatement placeholder for an argument to a sql aggregation function.  The query works fine if I replace the `?` placeholder with a numeric value and get rid of the `setDouble` call.

```java
    public static String QUERY = """
            SELECT DS_GET_QUANTILE(DS_QUANTILES_SKETCH("logins"), ?)  as "rank"
            FROM (SELECT ip, sum("login-counts") AS "attempts"
                  FROM "my-datasource"
                  WHERE __time >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '30' DAY
                  GROUP BY 1)
            """;

    void queryFails() throws SQLException {
        var connection = jdbcTemplate.getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection();
        var preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(QUERY);
        preparedStatement.setDouble(1, .75);
        var resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    }
```

The error is:

```
org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaSqlException: Error -1 (00000) : while preparing SQL: SELECT DS_GET_QUANTILE(DS_QUANTILES_SKETCH("attempts"), ?)  as "rank"
FROM (SELECT ip, sum("login-login_attempts") AS "attempts"
      FROM "metrics-default"
      WHERE __time >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '30' DAY
      GROUP BY 1)

    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.Helper.createException(Helper.java:54)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.Helper.createException(Helper.java:41)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaConnection.prepareStatement(AvaticaConnection.java:358)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaConnection.prepareStatement(AvaticaConnection.java:175)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:337)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java)
...
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.calcite.tools.ValidationException: org.apache.calcite.runtime.CalciteContextException: From line 1, column 8 to line 1, column 58: Cannot apply 'DS_GET_QUANTILE' to arguments of type 'DS_GET_QUANTILE(<OTHER>, <ANY>)'. Supported form(s): 'DS_GET_QUANTILE(<ANY>, <NUMERIC>)'
    at org.apache.druid.sql.avatica.DruidStatement.closeAndPropagateThrowable(DruidStatement.java:377)
    at org.apache.druid.sql.avatica.DruidStatement.prepare(DruidStatement.java:181)
    at org.apache.druid.sql.avatica.DruidMeta.prepare(DruidMeta.java:158)
```

It seems like it is passing the `?` to the database unsubstituted.

Is this a bug in the avatica driver or are placeholders not allowed in certain areas of a query?

Comment: If there is a `java.sql.SQLException` in the stacktrace, or anything derived from it, please provide it and its stack trace.

Comment: I have no experience with Calcite, but have you tried explicitly casting the parameter to the required type? In some database systems that solves type inference problems like this.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - wow, `CAST(? AS DOUBLE)` did the trick!  I would have never guessed this was a type issue, but rereading the exception hints at it.   Post an answer if you want to SO points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the root cause error message:

> java.lang.RuntimeException:
> org.apache.calcite.tools.ValidationException:
> org.apache.calcite.runtime.CalciteContextException: From line 1,
> column 8 to line 1, column 58: Cannot apply 'DS_GET_QUANTILE' to
> arguments of type 'DS_GET_QUANTILE(<OTHER>, <ANY>)'. Supported
> form(s): 'DS_GET_QUANTILE(<ANY>, <NUMERIC>)'

This is a problem with type inference for the parameter. Try explicitly casting the parameter to a numeric type, e.g. `cast(? as double)`.